# Create a generic type of more than two arguments via reflection?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, types

Basically, I have:

```
public class Gen<T, U> { }
```

And I want to create a generic type via reflection from that class. I tried the following, all yielded nulls:

```
var asm = typeof(Program).Assembly;
var gen1 = asm.GetType("Gen`2"); // null 
var gen2 = asm.GetType("Gen<>"); // null 
var gen3 = asm.GetType("Gen");   // null
```

And this didn't compile:

```
var t = typeof(Gen<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(string));
```

How can I achieve what I want? and why didn't the last statement compile? What about the "Gen`2" shouldn't this just work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
var t = typeof(Gen<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(string));
```

(note the comma between `<` and `>`)

To get the `Gen<T, U>` class through reflection, you must specify the *full name* of the type, including the namespace:

```
var gen = asm.GetType("TheNamespace.Gen`2");
```

If the `Gen<T, U>` class is nested, you must separate its name from its enclosing type name with `+`:

```
var gen = asm.GetType("TheNamespace.EnclosingType+Gen`2");
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. However, when I had my `Gen` class as a nested class in one of the namespace's classes, it didn't work. I even tried asm.GetType("TheNamespace.NestedType.Gen`2"); any idea why?

Comment: @vexe, I updated my answer to address the case of a nested class.